# Python script that receives Jira Webhooks data

Tags: python, jira, webhooks

Jira Webhooks allows the user to specify the URL of an application that will receive data, in json format, when an event occurs. For example when an issue is updated in Jira. I want to create a python script that will receive this data and print it out. How is the best way to create this python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat, but basically you need a Web server, which can receive POST requests and knows how to read corresponding parameters.
Several possibilities:

- Write simple script using builtin [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)
- Use some web framework (Django, Flask)
- Deploy your python script to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and configure [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)

And here is an [example](https://scalr-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/docs/2014/03/26/Webhooks+Handler+Sample+Code+Released+-+Python) application from Atlassian which can help you get started.